# How to add json object in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, json

My target is to append dictionaries in a list(i.e., in python) and now, I need similar operation in C language. How to achieve that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jansson.h>


int main()
{
    char* rfid_json_dict = NULL;
    json_t *root = json_object();
    json_t *json_arr = json_array();

    char id[] ="1";
    char value[] =  "D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-A431";


    json_object_set_new( root, "id", json_string(id) );
    json_object_set_new( root, "value", json_string(value) );
    rfid_json_dict = json_dumps(root, 0);
    printf("JSON:::%s\n",rfid_json_dict );
}
```

I have constructed a Json in C i.e.,

```
JSON:::{"id": "1", "value": "D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-A431"}
```

and How to add this in an array?

Suggestion - 1

As per the suggestion of kjhf, added the below lines with the above give example,

```
char *buf;
json_array_append( json_arr, root );

buf = json_dumps(json_arr ,0);
printf("JSON:::%s\n",buf );
```

I can able to achieve the desired result,

```
JSON:::[{"id": "1", "value": "D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-A431"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jansson library comes with a [tutorial page](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) and documentation for the json_array.

You're looking for either [json_array_set](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apiref.html?#c.json_array_set)(json_t *array, size_t index, json_t *value) or [json_array_append](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apiref.html?#c.json_array_append)(json_t *array, json_t *value).